# How to average to 1 minute

Tags: r, data-science

I am trying to average to 1 min. In my data I have some data points that were taken within the same minute and this is not letting me plot my data. For example my data time stamps might look like:

```
2019-12-04 16:59:27 
2019-12-04 16:59:27 
2019-12-04 16:59:28
2019-12-04 16:59:29
2019-12-04 16:59:29
2019-12-04 16:59:30
```

How do I average this so that it consolidates those duplicate data points into a 1 min average?

Comment: You can remove the seconds, and if they have the same time in minutes (`16:59`), they shall fall in the same minute. And what you need is just to collapse the duplicates.

Comment: It may be worth showing how you are trying to plot this as there is no reason why you cannot plot by the second

Comment: @PanwenWang That won't work as I have 59 data points for each minute, I'm trying to eliminate just those duplicated seconds because I need the data from every second of every minute.

Comment: Please share a line of your desired output, I'm not clear on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything dates/times, the `lubridate` package is the way to go. In this case, you want `round_date()`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
#First, create your dataset (at least, what I think it might look like)
df <- tibble(
  time = ymd_hms(c(
    "2019-12-04 16:59:27" ,
    "2019-12-04 16:59:27" , 
    "2019-12-04 16:59:28",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:29",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:29",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:30"
    ))
) %>%
  mutate(time = round_date(time, unit = "minutes")) %>% #Round the time variable to the nearest minute.
  distinct() #remove duplicate rows.
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  time               
  <dttm>             
1 2019-12-04 16:59:00
2 2019-12-04 17:00:00
```

UPDATE: Looks like you're just looking for distinct rows, in which case just the `distinct()` function will do.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
#First, create your dataset
df <- tibble(
  time = ymd_hms(c(
    "2019-12-04 16:59:27" ,
    "2019-12-04 16:59:27" , 
    "2019-12-04 16:59:28",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:29",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:29",
    "2019-12-04 16:59:30"
    ))
) %>%
  distinct() #remove duplicate rows.
```

Output 2:

```
  time               
  <dttm>             
1 2019-12-04 16:59:27
2 2019-12-04 16:59:28
3 2019-12-04 16:59:29
4 2019-12-04 16:59:30
```

Comment: But I need to just eliminate the duplicated seconds as I need the data for every second of every minute

Comment: Okay, I'll try to update accordingly (P.S. It's good practice to share your desired output)

Comment: If this answers your question and you could mark it as the answer, it would be appreciated!